# Simple question on weak law of large numbers

Tags: self-study, law-of-large-numbers

[image]

What I have so far is this:

I need to find the E[.] and V[.] and show that the expected value equals to $\sigma^2$  and variance tends to 0 as T -> $\infty$. I already found the Expected value to be equal to $\sigma^2$. How do i show the variance tends to 0?

Is my approach right?

Comment: You might note that the weak LLN doesn't require any assumptions on the variance of the distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law

Comment: @Samuel so does this mean, showing that the expected value of this term is equal to $\sigma^2$ enough to prove convergence in probability?

Comment: Weak LLN says that sample average of iid data with finite expected values converges in probability to that expected value - so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Samuel noted, you do not need variance to show law of large numbers. However if we assume that variance exists (in this case $Ex_t^4<\infty$) then law of large numbers follows if we show that expectation converges and variance goes to zero.

In your case simply note that

$$Var(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Tx_t^2)=\frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{s=1}^Tcov(x_t^2,x_s^2)$$

Now recall what the independence assumption says about covariance and then simple algebra should give you desired answer.

Comment: ahh! cool, I got it; I dont know why, but my professor keeps saying "sufficient conditions for wlln to kick in is E[x] -> constant and V[x] -> 0. and calls it chebyshev's lemma. I suppose he means its not required, but just sufficient.

Comment: Yes it is sufficient. And yes it follows from the chebyshev's lemma: $P(|X-EX|>t)\le \frac{Var(X)}{t^2}$